# Sed Replace Help

Tags: linux, sed, replace

I need some assistance with some sed replaces:

```
sed -ri 's#logging {
/*      If you want to enable debugging, eg. using the 'rndc trace' command,
 *      named will try to write the 'named.run' file in the $directory (/var/named").
 *      By default, SELinux policy does not allow named to modify the /var/named" directory,
 *      so put the default debug log file in data/ :
 */
    channel default_debug {
            file "data/named.run";
            severity dynamic;
    };
};
#logging {
/*      If you want to enable debugging, eg. using the 'rndc trace' command,
 *      named will try to write the 'named.run' file in the $directory (/var/named").
 *      By default, SELinux policy does not allow named to modify the /var/named" directory,
 *      so put the default debug log file in data/ :
 */
    channel default_debug {
            file "data/named.run";
            severity dynamic;
    };
category security { null; };
};
#g' /etc/named.conf
```

Basically I'm trying to add "category security { null; };" to /etc/named.conf (different line numbers on different servers) on quite a few systems, and sed is failing out on me.

Any tips and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file and enter this

```
/severity dynamic;/ {
N
s/\( *};\)/\1\ncategory security {null;};/g
}
```

then save and run it like this

```
sed -f file /etc/named.conf
```